# Duplicate an entry

Tags: channel-entries

I have a channel that has a lot of fields and several entries are similar to each other. So I want to be able to duplicate an entry and then make changes to it instead of having to retype everything from scratch.

Is there a way to do this in the CP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Found this extension: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner

Comment: Mark your own answer as correct, please.